# Is it possible to find a node by its attributes in XML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, mapping

Say I'm loading an XML as so :

```
url    = "http://www.mywebsite.com/awesome_xml.xml"
xml    = HTTParty.get url, format: :xml
```

And my XML looks like this :

```
    <activity id="6RhUUfdP8b1" type="objective">
        <name lang="und">Results</name>
    </activity>

    <activity id="6bKsxwZaTjT" type="module">
        <name lang="und">Wild and whacky?</name>
    </activity>
```

And I want to collect all the `<activity>` nodes that have a type equal to `module`.

What is the most elegant way to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org) and `css` selector:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.mywebsite.com/awesome_xml.xml"))

xml.css("activity[type='module']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath:

```
//activity[@type='module']
```